# Rewrite URLs with no id following folder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I like that I substitute id:

```
RewriteRule ^product/([0-9]+) http://example.com/index.php?Id=$1 [L]
```

How can I remove the `product/` from the request if it does not include the numbers?

For example, from:

```
example.com/product/img/img.gif
```

To:

```
example.com/img/img.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `product` folder,create `.htaccess` file that contains this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```